# TS2322: Type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date' even though I check it

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is what I have so far:

I have one Array of Dates:
`trackedElementsTimestamps: Date[];` and one Array of Objects: `trackedElements: TrackingEvent[];`

In *TrackingEvent* there is a Date: `timestamp?: Date;`

My goal is to get every *timestamp* out of *trackedElements* and push it into *trackedElementsTimestamps*:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.trackedElements.length; i++) {
   if (this.trackedElements[i].timestamp != undefined) {
      this.trackedElementsTimestamps[i] = this.trackedElements[i].timestamp;
   } else {
      console.log("trackedElements[" + i + "].timestamp is undefined")
   }
}
```

At `this.trackedElementsTimestamps[i]` it throws following error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
```

Also I don't want to use `!` because it can produce a problem later on in my code.
What's another way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

Cast it as Date.

```
this.trackedElementsTimestamps[i] = this.trackedElements[i].timestamp as Date;
```

Or assign the current loop item to a local variable

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.trackedElements.length; i++) {
   const currItem = this.trackedElements[i]; 

   if (currItem.timestamp != undefined) {
      this.trackedElementsTimestamps[i] = currItem.timestamp;
   } else {
      console.log("trackedElements[" + i + "].timestamp is undefined")
   }
}
```

cheers

Comment: Thank you! The first option is working just fine.
I didn't know you can cast it like that

Answer (score 0):

Null checks in javascript are usually done with

```
if (!!currItem.timestamp) {
    // now there's a value
}
```

VS code and the angular compiler will be able to narrow down the type inside the if clause.

So in your case

```
this.trackedElementsTimestamps = this.trackedElements.filter(te => !!te.timestamp).map(te => te.timestamp);
```

Or if you're using observables:

```
this.trackedElementsTimestamps$ = this.trackedElements$.pipe(filter(te => !!te.timestamp)).pipe(map(te => te.timestamp));
```

Which you can then show in your view

```
<span *ngFor="let timestamp of (trackedElementsTimestamps$ | async)">
    {{ timestamp }}
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best shot is using a `.forEach` or a `.map` rather than a classical `for` loop. TypeScript has some issues when iterating using a classic loop for reasons that I am not qualified enough to explain.

If you care about indices:

```
trackedElements.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element.timestamp) {
        trackedElementsTimestamps[index] = element.timestamp;
    }
})
```

If you don't care about indices:

```
trackedElements.forEach(element => {
    if (element.timestamp) {
        trackedElementsTimestamps.push(element.timestamp);
    }
})
```

Comment: This can cause different issues because the indices no longer match.

Comment: @Clashsoft Where in the question is that specified as a requirement?

Comment: In the code. It may not be explicitly written in the prose but matching indices is what OPs current solution does and it may be for a reason. You can’t just change the semantics of the code apart from solving the problem in the question. Thats why I warned that your solution may have unintended side effects.

Comment: What OPs solution does is throwing an error. Quoting literally: "My goal is to get every timestamp out of trackedElements and **push** it into trackedElementsTimestamps". It's a valid warning, but you can't just change the semantics of the prose.